# Very basic English grammar parser

Tags: c++, parsing, nlp

I'm writing a very basic parser(mostly just to better understand how they work) that takes a user's input of a select few words, detects whether the sentence structure is OK or Not OK, and outputs the result. The grammar is:

Sentence:
Noun Verb

Article Sentence

Sentence Conjunction Sentence

Conjunction:
"and"
"or"
"but"

Noun:
"birds"
"fish"
"C++"

Verb:
"rules"
"fly"
"swim"

Article:
"the"

Writing the grammar was simple. It's implementing the code that is giving me some trouble. My psuedocode for it is:

```
main()
get user input (string words;)
while loop (cin >> words)
call sentence()
end main()

sentence()
call noun()
if noun() call verb() (if verb is true return "OK" ???)(else "not ok"???)
else if not noun() call article()
                if article() call sentence() (if sentence is true "OK"???)(else "not"?)
else if not noun() call conjunction()
                   if sentence() conjunction() sentence() - no idea how to implement
                                                             return "OK"
else "not ok"
```

So there is my extremely sloppy psuedo code. I have a few questions on implementing it.

1. For the word functions (noun, verb, etc.) how should I go about checking if they are true? (as in checking if the user's input has birds, fish, fly, swim, etc.)
2. How should I handle the conjunction call and the output?
3. Should I handle the output from the main function or the call functions?
4. None of the above questions matter if my psuedo code is completely wrong. Is there anything wrong with the basics?

As an added note, I'm on a Chapter 6 exercise of Programming: Practice and Principles Using C++ so I'd prefer to use language syntax that I've already learned, so anything that falls into the category of advanced programming probably isn't very helpful. (The exercise specifically says not to use tokens, so count those out.)

Thanks in advance

Last Edit: In the book's public group I asked the same question and Bjarne Stroustrup commented back saying he put the exercise solution online. He basically had the input read into the sentence function and used if statements to return true or false. However, he didn't use articles so mine was much more complex. I guess if I've learned anything from this exercise its that when dealing with a lot of user input, tokenization is key (from what I know so far.) Here is my code for now. I may go back to it later because it is still very buggy and basically only returns if the sentence is OK and can't handle things like (noun, conjunction, sentence), but for now I'm moving on.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

bool article(string words)
{
               if (words == "the")
               return true;
               else return false;        
}

bool verb(string words)
{
               if (words == "rules" || words == "fly" || words == "swim")
               return true;
               else return false;                   
}

bool noun(string words)
{
               if (words == "birds" || words == "fish" || words == "c++")
               return true;
               else return false;                   
}

bool conjunction(string words)
{
              if (words == "and" || words == "but" || words == "or")
              return true;
              else return false;                  
}

bool sentence()
{
string w1;
string w2;
string w3;
string w4;

cin >> w1;
if (!noun(w1) && !article(w1)) return false; // grammar of IFS!

cin >> w2;
if (noun(w1) && !verb(w2)) return false;
if (article(w1) && !noun(w2)) return false;

cin >> w3;
if (noun(w1) && verb(w2) && (w3 == ".")) return true;
if (verb(w2) && !conjunction(w3)) return false;
if (noun(w2) && !verb(w3)) return false;
if (conjunction(w3)) return sentence();

cin >> w4;
if (article(w1) && noun(w2) && verb(w3) && (w4 == ".")) return true;
if (!conjunction(w4)) return false;
if (conjunction(w4)) return sentence();
}


int main()
{                                   
cout << "Enter sentence. Use space then period to end.\n";
            bool test = sentence();
            if (test)
               cout << "OK\n";
            else
               cout << "not OK\n";
```

keep_window_open();
    }

Comment: I edited the message to show some ugly code I threw together to show what I mean. Error messages and other features will be handled later after I get the basics down.

Comment: Do you want to write a parser from scratch? Or do you want to know how to use the parser generator tools to build a parser you can customize?

Comment: I want to write it from scratch.

Comment: Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser#C_implementation

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that it seems to be reading each words individually. How can I get the sentence function to read every word without using tokens?

Comment: I'm playing around with using a getline function, but not sure how to set the delimiter to just be a new line.

Comment: Getline now works, but I always receive a "Not Ok."

Comment: I've succumbed I'm tokenizing.

Comment: What a cool discussion! I have always wanted to understand grammars and lexers etc. This is a nice intro. Thanks. Fav.

Comment: @Alex, could you post the code you're using with getline?  I'm curious.

Answer (score 10):

Ok. If you really want to do it by hand :-(

There are two parts to this problem:

- Lexical analysis
- Syntactic Analysis.
- We can ignore the Symantic analysis as this is why up ther.

First you have tokenize the input stream into resonable tokens. Words would be an obvios choice but that would leave a lot of work for the syntactic phase. So I would group up your words into the following types (Conjunction,Noun,Verb,Article) and then write a lexer to return the correct Lexems.

```
Lexer.cpp
enum Lexeme { END,Conjunction,Noun,Verb,Article };
Lexem getNextLexme(std::istream in)
{
    std::string word;
    in >> word;

    if (!in) {return END;}

         if (word == "and")   return Conjunction;
    else if (word == "birds") return Noun;
    else if (word == "fly")   return Verb;
    else if (word == "the")   return Article;

    ... etc
}
```

So now you can wrtie your syntactic parser in terms of the simplified token stream.

```
bool ParseSentence(std::istream in)
{
    Lexeme token = getNextLexme(in);
    switch(token)
    {
        case Noun:    if (!parseVerb(in))
                      {    return false;
                      }
                      return parseConjunctionOrEnd(in);
        case Article: return ParseSentence();
        case END:     return true;
    }
}
bool parseVerb(std::istream in)
{
    Lexeme token = getNextLexeme(in);
    if (token != Verb) { /*ERROR*/ return false;}
    return true;
 }
 // etc
```

Your other option with syntactic analyasis is to build a state table. But that involves hand analysing the grammer and determing the states. This should only be attepted with the most trivial of grammers, anything bigger than you have here should be left to tools that can generate the state table auto-magically.

So Assuming the grammer I defined in my original post below:
And hoping I get it correct as I am not an inflable tool :-)

```
State 1:   Start <Nothing Happened>
               Article -> State 2
               Noun -> State 3
               Otherwise Error
State 2:   Seen Article.
               Noun -> State 3
               Otherwise Error
State 3:   Seen Noun  in Sentence.
               Verb -> State 4
               Otherwise Error
State 4:   Seen Noun Verb
               End -> State 5
               Conjunction -> State 1
State 5:   Finished:

State 0:   Error State.


int stateTable[][]    // CurrentState,CurrentObject
           = {/*State 0: Error State:*/{},
                                       // END,Conjunction,Noun,Verb,Article 
              /*State 1: Start*/       {  0,  0,          3,   0,   2},
              /*State 2: Article*/     {  0,  0,          3,   0,   0},
              /*State 3: Noun*/        {  0,  0,          0,   4,   0},
              /*State 4: Noun Verb*/   {  5,  1,          0,   0,   0},
              /*State 5: End*/         {}
             };

bool parseSentence(std::iostream& in)
{
    int currentState = 1;
    while((currentState != 0) && (currentState != 5))
    {
        int token = getNextLexme(in);
        currentState = stateTable[currentState][token];
    }
    return currentState == 5;
}
```

Comment: The exercise said not to bother with tokens and just to read into a string. However, this has definitely put me on the right track. I'll comment and edit the post if I get it.

Comment: @Alex...  This is about as good of an answer you will get without writing the whole thing for you.  Combine this answer with Barry Brown's answer and you have a fairly complete solution.  Martin's answer is giving you the code, and pointing you in the right direction to top-down recurse the grammar.  It is definitely better to tokenize the input stream as Martin has done.  HOwever, to parse like this, you need to re-form your grammar as Barry has suggested.  Make sure that it fits the requirements for top-down parsing.

Comment: The exercise specifically says not to use tokens, so I'm going to try to pull out a few more tricks before I resort to that. Also I'm definitely going to reform the grammar, however creating classes seems unnecessary (unless I'm using tokens.)

Comment: @Alex... you can pull this exercise off without tokens, but it does not complicate it much and it is definitely a cleaner/easier route to go.

Comment: I know I've got the code down except for one major flaw. The sentence function() needs to be able to read every word input rather than just one at a time. Is tokenization the only way to accomplish this? If so, damn you Stroustrup!

Comment: I'm using a getline function to save all of the words input by the user. It's now only outputting 1 result, but it always outputs "Not Ok." Not sure why....

Answer (score 6):

I'm intrigued by this question. I'm going to help the OP, Alex, cook something up, but since I don't know C++ very well, it'll be in pseudo-C++. It won't use lex/yacc, either, because Alex wants to learn how they're made. Tools such as lex and yacc become "black boxes" if you use them. I don't have time to put it all together right now, but I can work on it piece by piece over a few hours. I just wanted to get this started now.

The first thing we need to do is clean up the grammar. You have a sentence defined this way:

```
sentence : noun verb
         | article sentence
         | sentence conjunction sentence
```

This grammar is flawed. A sentence such as "a the fish swim" is valid because sentence is defined in terms of itself. Recursion is a normal part of grammars, but it needs to be handled correctly. I'm going to hazard a guess that you don't want two or more articles to appear in a row.

A better grammar for sentence could be:

```
sentence : clause conjunction clause
         | clause

clause : nounphrase verbphrase

nounphrase : noun
           | article noun
```

This removes the unconstrained recursion which could cause infinite loops.

Now we're ready to tackle the parser itself. Since this is C++, we might as well make it object-oriented. I gotta scoot for now, but I'll give you a hint: there's going to be a class for each one of the production rules.

Comment: "Since this is C++, we might as well make it object-oriented. [...] there's going to be a class for each one of the production rules." Somehow, this says a lot about what's wrong with the state of the world today. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reformed grammar. I'm going to have to use classes if I tokenize it, but there's got to be a solution not involving tokens. I'm going to try a few more tricks (maybe make a vector of strings?) and if I can't figure it out I'll resort to tokenization.

Comment: Yup, I'm going to tokenize. But it's late now so I'll work on it tomorrow morning. However, don't I just need a token class to get the inputs? I don't see any particular reason to make a class for every rule.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so... I won't have answers to your specific questions, but I want to point you to some general ideas to think about when working on this.  First of all, parsing is hard.  You have a simple grammar, but it can STILL be hard.  Compiler front-ends are responsible for parsing... just to give some context.

There are two basic types of parsing... top down parsing and bottom up parsing. They are named by how they traverse a syntax tree (Think about what sort of syntax tree is going to be created for possible constructs). Top down parsing is easy, and will probably work for what you want to do.  The most common top-down parsing method is Recursive Descent parsing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

However, to use recursive descent parsing, your grammar must be in a certain format... for some grammars, it is impossible to recursive descent parse them.  You should be able to reform your grammar to fit this though.

Top-down parsers are easy to write... as you will only need a few functions for a small language.

The second way to parse is bottom-up parsing.  This is commonly used in compilers as it does not have the restrictions top-down has.  It is also easier to do error-reporting if the given string does not fit the language.

Bottom-up parsers are HARD to write... most people use a parser generator to do the work.  I've worked with YACC quite a bit.  You basically input the grammar (and actions to take when that rule is matched) and it parses the grammer.

Bottom-up parsers use something called shift-reduce parsing.  This is the method of processing the input and matching the rules.

Looking at your code again, I'd say it is possible for you to use a top-down parser.  Sorry I can't give specific code, but a google of top-down parser examples (or recursive descent parser examples) would probably turn up the code you need.

Comment: The example from the chapter (a calculator example) used bottom-up parsing for an order of operations grammar. However, this seems different since it isn't checking for nouns and verbs in a strict ascending or descending order, but is rather checking to see "if x is true, make sure y is also true." It pretty much works top-down, but has a few twists. I'm going to post some unfinished code in a second to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Most parsing like program text parsing is done with formal grammar parsers.  English and most spoken languages are not formal grammars and you're going to have a *very* hard time parsing them.  This problem has tied up PHDs for decades without a lot of success.

Comment: I don't think that's the point of this question.  He's already come up with a simplified version of English grammar which is formal enough to parse.  His question is more about how to create a parsing program in general.

Comment: Yes the question was. How do I parse this grammer.

Answer (score 1):

**Parts of Speech**

To get parts of speech you will need [a dictionary list with parts of speech](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/3203). Besides a hashtable mapping words to lists of parts of speech, another possible way to check for part(s) of speech is to load each set of words for each part of speech into its own [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (sort of a compressed hashed map from strings to booleans).

Answer (score 1):

One aspect of grammars for natural languages is that they are often ambigious.  For example, the english sentance:

> I once shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajams I'll never know
>   
>  -- Groucho Marx

The phrase 'in my pajamas' ambigiously describes The subject 'I' or the object 'elephant'.  Without semantic context it would be impossible to build an AST correctly.

If you wish to avoid this, you will probably need some way of treating ambiguity in a useful way.  One strategy is to produce all possible derivations of ambiguous phrases.  One tool that makes this possible is an [Earley Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_algorithm).  Unlike other types of parser, such as recursive descent parsers, Earley parsers generate all derivations in the form of parser state transitions, rather than a simple tree.  In practice this isn't any harder to work with.

Comment: It's hard to wreck a nice beach.

Comment: Another ambiguity in natural languages is words that can be one of two or more types. For instance, these nouns/verbs: fly, call, stack, wreck. And this noun/verb/adjective: light. I think you have your work cut out for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex and Bison:

Grammer Rule in Bison:

```
%%

English            :   SentenceList

SentenceList       :   Sentence
                   |   Article  Sentence
                   |   Sentence Conjunction Sentence

Sentence           :   Noun Verb


Conjunction        :   TOKEN_WordAnd
                   |   TOKEN_WordOr
                   |   TOKEN_WordBut


Noun               :   TOKEN_WORD_BIRDS
                   |   TOKEN_WORD_FISH
                   |   TOKEN_WORD_CPP

Verb:              :   TOKEN_WORD_RULES
                   |   TOKEN_WORD_FLY
                   |   TOKEN_WRD_SWIM

Article            :   TOKEN_WORD_THE
%%
```

Comment: Why the down vote. I can think of a better way to parse a well defined grammer! Use the corect tool for the job.

Comment: Maybe because the OP wasn't looking for a parser - he was looking for help in writing one...

Comment: Maybe. But this is writting one.

Comment: Having a tool take your grammar and generating a parser isn't quite the same at all as writing a parser.

Comment: I would argue it is: The only difference is that you do not need to set with paper and pencil for 10 hours generating a state table. The hard part is defining a valid grammer and that is done by you not the tools.

Comment: I think you're both right, in a way.  On the one hand, the OP wanted to write a parser from scratch, and that's not what this is.  This is someone else's work.  On the other hand, the OP could inspect this work and build his own parser based on this one's design.  He would need to translate from C# to C++, of course, which adds a new dimension of complexity to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a loot to [Ubiquity](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/ubiquity/), it's a plugin for Firefox that aims to use natural language to do common web tasks (it's written in JavaScript but maybe you can get a general algorithm that would be usefull)

Answer (score -1):

Before you get too far writing a parser, might I suggest learning the pair of lex and yacc or flex and bison? These tools were specifically made for creating parsers and lexers.

They will automatically generated your c/c++ (maybe other) code, so you will not have to worry about all sorts of boundary cases for user arguments. You could whip up the grammar you have above in under 30 minutes.

As for your questions:

> For the word functions (noun, verb,
>   etc.) how should I go about checking
>   if they are true? (as in checking if
>   the user's input has birds, fish, fly,
>   swim, etc.)

A generous use of strcasecmp() is called for here, with all sorts of error checking as well.

> How should I handle the conjunction
>   call and the output?

I don't really understand too much what you mean here. I'd just return some sort of sentinel value if its valid or not.

> Should I handle the output from the
>   main function or the call functions?

Mostly from the call functions, since these have the individual functionality you're concerned with. main() is just glue to hold it together.

> None of the above questions matter if
>   my psuedo code is completely wrong. Is
>   there anything wrong with the basics?

It looks doable the way you have, but you will save yourself a huge headache by switching to lex/yacc or flex/bison

Comment: I guess because he's asking because he wants to learn how they work. I agree that learning parsers with a tool will teach you a lot. *Then* write your own.